# Rethinkdb with nodejs and expresso

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, expresso

I am trying to use `rethinkdb` and test it via `expresso`. I have function

```
module.exports.setup = function() {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  r.connect({host: dbConfig.host, port: dbConfig.port }, function (err, connection) {
     if (err) return deferred.reject(err);
     else deferred.resolve();
  });
 return deferred.promise;
});
```

I am testing it like this

```
  module.exports = {
    'setup()': function() {
        console.log("in setup rethink");

        db.setup().then(function(){
            console.log(clc.green("Sucsessfully connected to db!"));
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('error');
            assert.isNotNull(err, "error");
        });

    }
  };
```

And I am runing code like this

```
expresso db.test.js
```

But expresso shows `error 100% 1 tests` even in case of error.
I tried to put `throw err;` in `catch`, but nothing changes.

But if I put `assert.eql(1, 2, "error");` in the begining of `setup()` it fails as expected;

Is there something, that caches errors? How can I make it fail as it should be?
For `squalize` I found

```
Sequelize.Promise.onPossiblyUnhandledRejection(function(e, promise) {
    throw e;
});
```

Is there something like this for rethink db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this test is asynchronous, and you're treating it as a synchronous test. You need to do the following:

```
  module.exports = {
    'setup()': function(beforeExit, assert) {
        var success;
        db.setup().then(function(){
            success = true;
        }).catch(function(err){
            success = false;
            assert.isNotNull(err, "error");
        });

        beforeExit(function() {
            assert.isNotNull(undefined, 'Ensure it has waited for the callback');
        });
    }
  };
```

**Mocha vs Express**

You should consider taking a look at [mocha.js](http://mochajs.org/), which has a much nicer API for asynchronous operations by passing the `done` function. The same test would look like this:

```
  module.exports = {
    'setup()': function(done) {
        db.setup().then(function(){
            assert.ok(true);
        }).catch(function(err){
            assert.isNotNull(err, "error");
        })
        .then(function () {
            done();
        });
    }
  };
```

**Promises**

The first function you wrote can be re-written in the following manner, because the RethinkDB driver, by default, returns a promise on all operations.

```
module.exports.setup = function() {
    return r.connect({host: dbConfig.host, port: dbConfig.port });
});
```

Comment: It worked when I changed `assert.isNotNull(undefined, 'Ensure it has waited for the callback');` to assert.eql(1, 2, 'Ensure it has waited for the callback'); But I did not get why.

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake. It should be `assert.isNotNull(success, '...');`. You could also try `assert.isDefined(success, '...');`